# Antminers - Can you monitor via SNMP, and set up configuration file Chron Jobs

Tags: mining-hardware, miner-configuration, cgminer, antminer

I have an antminer and its very loud. Is it possible to set up a chron job to stop mining, apply a new config file with a lower clockrate and set fan speed overnight? Then to do the same at 7am but overclock it to compensate for the lower hashrate overnight.

Are they also compatible via SNMP? Would like to monitor the temps and if the system is rebooting itself.

Answer (score 1):

The Antminer software doesn’t support anything for automation like this, though you can ssh in and make these modifications manually. There is no support for remote monitoring with SNMP, but there is an exposed cgminer API for remote configuration.